# SVN merge error: Filesystem has no item path not found

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I'm attempting to merge changes between 2 branches and receiving the following error:

```
svn: '/svn/***/!svn/bc/1234/***/branches/integration/***' path not found
```

Both branches are from trunk, and the branch I want to merge changes into (integration) is newer than the branch I'm merging changes from (my code). When I look at the log at the top level of the entire repo, I see revision 1234 is someone deleting a folder (irrelevant folder not related to the code I'm trying to merge.) I had no problems merging the integration branch into my code prior to this.

I get the same error with Subclipse and Tortoise. Using subversion 1.8. I've cleared the Tortoise cache which did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the option to select a range of revisions, choosing the revision my original branch began at until the very last revision. Not sure what that changes as it should be the same as all eligible revisions, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After an svn upgrade from 1.7 to 1.14 on Centos 7, I received multiple errors like this ("path not found", "Invalid filesystem path syntax", "Target path '/repo/abc/def' does not exist", etc) when using Subclipse/Eclipse and attempting to synchronize the repo, or view svn history, or other svn commands.

The svn 1.14 installation process saved the svn 1.7 configuration file here (needed for reference when editing the 1.14 config file):

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf.rpmsave
```

Configuration file used by svn 1.14 (might be different file location for other systems, but maybe under /etc/httpd/conf.d somewhere):

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf
```

There were differences between the 1.7 and 1.14 config files. I updated the 1.14 file to this, noting that SVNParentPath needed to be used rather than SVNPath:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /svn
  #SVNPath /opt/repo/
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repos"
  AuthUserFile /opt/WANdisco/apache22/conf/svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/authz
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Then create the directory to store the password file:

```
mkdir -p /opt/WANdisco/apache22/conf/
```

Re-created svn user(s):

```
htpasswd -m -c /opt/WANdisco/apache22/conf/svn.passwd my-user
```

and checking /svn/authz for existing config:

```
[groups]
admin=my-user

[/]
@admin = rw
* =
```

Restart apache:

```
systemctl restart httpd
systemctl -l status httpd
```

Issued `svn upgrade` command for working copies on the server, and also using context-sensitive menu for all Subversion projects in Eclipse.

This fixed the issues :)